# Angular2 bind property to Component Input

Tags: angular, binding, components

I have an Object 'orderItem' with an number property 'amount'.

for display i`m binding to 'amount' -> {{orderItem.amount}}

To increment and decremet the amount i want to use a nested component 'inputNumberControl'

when passing the complete orderItem to the nested component

`<input-number-control [item]="orderItem"></input-number-control>`

and there manipulating the amount everything workls like expected,  amount in parentcopmonent is incremented and decremented.

I d like to use the control more flexible passing only the property to the nested component

`<input-number-control [item]="orderItem.amount"></input-number-control>`

but then the amount is not changing in the parent component.

Any Idea whats the reason for this behaviour and how to handle it ?

Code of the number-control-component

```
export class InputNumberComponent{
    @Input() item:OrderItem;

decrementAmount()
{
    if(this.item.amount>1)this.item.amount--;
}
incrementAmount()
{
    this.item.amount++;
}
}
```

this works fine

```
    @Input() value:number;

decrementAmount()
{
    if(this.value>1)this.value--;
}
incrementAmount()
{
    this.value++;
}
```

doesnt work

Comment: In your `input-number-control` component how do you change value of `item`? Show me only that code.

Comment: i`ll add it in the original Post ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing value of `item` in `input-number-control` and want to reflect the same in parent (while using an object) you can go with Two-Way data binding of Anguar2 with **[()] - @Input xxx; @Output xxxChange;** syntax together;

---

```
<input-number-control [(item)]="orderItem.amount"></input-number-control>
```

---

```
import {Input,Output,EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

export class InputNumberComponent{
    @Input() item;                            //<-----Note - changed line
    @Output() itemChange=new EventEmitter();  

  decrementAmount()
  {
    if(this.item>1)
    this.itemChange.emit(this.item--);
  }
  incrementAmount()
  {
    this.itemChange.emit(this.item++);

  }
}
```

This Demo is not made of your code, but its relevant one which would help you.

**Demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/9D6UIZcI9Lc2EOJjsYy4?p=preview**